# How do I Dynamically Preselect an item in a html.DropDownlist in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

is there way thats i can preselect an item when the page loads or posts to the server..

this is what i have right now..

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("dllMonths", 
    new SelectList(new List<string>() {
       "", "January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "June", 
       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
       "December"}), 
    new { onchange="this.form.submit();" })%>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the SelectedValue property of the SelectList, or pass it as second parameter to SelectList constructor.

```
<% = Html.DropDownList ( "dllMonths", 
                           new SelectList ( new List ( ) 
                                          { "", "January", "Feburary", "March", 
                                            "April", "June", "July", "August", 
                                            "September", "October", "November", 
                                            "December" },
                                          "April" ), 
                           new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" } 
                       )%>
```

Comment: I would go a little further and say that you should use an overload with the selected item argument.

Comment: i think that was what i said :)

Comment: He gave two choices; I'm saying the first is really the only acceptable one. But I did up-vote since he got it right.

Comment: yea, actually i would agree on that. It will probably save a function call as well i would think